# Jekyll nested front matter not displaying in layout template for loop

Tags: loops, jekyll, liquid, yaml-front-matter

I am trying to loop over a nested list in my posts font matter and display an associated image (using svg) for each nested item

post front matter:

```
---  
layout: post
title: title of this post
spec:
- name: tee
- name: mobile
---
```

using a for loop in my post.html file

```
<div>
    <h4>specs</h4>

    {% for item in page.spec %}
    <svg class='spec-icon'><use xlink:href="#icons_{{item.name}}"/</svg>
    {% endfor %}

</div>
```

I would like this to render like below

```
 <div>
     <h4>specs</h4>

     <svg class='spec-icon'><use xlink:href="#icons_tee"/></svg>
     <svg class='spec-icon'><use xlink:href="#icons_mobile"/></svg>

 </div>
```

for every neseted name:vale pair under spec:, I would like there to be a unique svg element created with that nested value included in the #id

???

Comment: Your code works well here. Do you have a repository url to help you debug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
---  
layout: post
title: title of this post
spec: [tee, mobile]
---
```

Then:

```
<div>
    <h4>specs</h4>

    {% for item in page.spec %}
    <svg class='spec-icon'><use xlink:href="#icons_{{ item }}"/</svg>
    {% endfor %}

</div>
```

Hope to have helped! Let me know if this works, yeah?

Comment: @savage0banana, does it works? If so, would you please mark the answer as correct? :) Thanks!